I'm having issues applying a maximun and minimun band to my graph using fill_between()
I have already made graph and need to implement maximum and minimum for two of its curve lines. My problem is that the max and min band that I made so far doesn't go all the way through the X axis.
dados = {'Trajetória Prometida': {'2023': -0.5,
                             '2024': 0,
                             '2025': 0.5,
                             '2026': 1},
        'Nova Trajetória': {'2023': None,
                        '2024': 0,
                        '2025': 0,
                        '2026': 0.25},
        'Focus': {'2023': -2.3,
            '2024': -0.8,
            '2025': -0.6,
            '2026': -0.5},
        'SAMI': {'2023': None,
             '2024': -0.7,
             '2025': -0.8,
             '2026': -0.6},
             }
df = pd.DataFrame(dados)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(5,5))

max1 = [-0.25, 0.25, 0.75, 1.25]
min1 = [-0.75, -0.25, 0.25, 0.75]
ax.fill_between(df['Trajetória Prometida'], max1, min1, alpha=.5, linewidth=2)
ax.plot(df)

How it is going:

How it should look:


You should use df.index as x in fill_between:
ax.fill_between(df.index, max1, min1, alpha=.5, linewidth=2)

So can also compute the value of min/max automatically:
s = df['Trajetória Prometida']
ax.fill_between(df.index, s-0.25, s+0.25, alpha=.5, linewidth=2)

Output:

For all columns:
for col in df:
    s = df[col]
    ax.fill_between(df.index, s-0.25, s+0.25, alpha=.5, linewidth=2)


